# Personalized Query JPA

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm creating a project manager, where the user can have multiple projects, but a project can only belong to one user (@OnetoMany). I managed to make the relationship and everything, the problem is that I wanted to make a custom query displaying all the projects of only one user. Could you give me an idea of ​​how to do this custom query, please?

**Relationship in User Class**

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL) @JoinColumn(name = "id_user") private List<Project> projects = new ArrayList<>();
```

**ProjectController Class**

```
@GetMapping("/listar/{userId}") public ResponseEntity<List<Project>> listProjectsByUser(@PathVariable Long userId) { return ResponseEntity.ok(projectService.listProjectsByUser(userId));}
```

**ProjectService Class**

```
public List<Project> listProjectsByUser(Long userId) { return projectRepository.findProjectByUser(userId);}
```

Finally the @Query created in **ProjectRepository Class**

```
@Query("SELECT p FROM Project p WHERE p.id = :id_user") List<Project> findProjectByUser(Long id);
```

This is the Projects table that is being generated by JPA, notice that I am trying to do a "SELECT" using the column "id_user"

[image: Projects' Table]

I tried make this Query, but it gives this error

Named parameter not bound : id_user; nested exception is org.hibernate.QueryException: Named parameter not bound : id_user

Answer (score 0):

u can try this way 
replace id_user -> id

```
@Query("SELECT p FROM Project p WHERE p.id = :id") 
List<Project> findProjectByUser(Long id);
```

or replace id -> id_user if u want

```
@Query("SELECT p FROM Project p WHERE p.id = :id_user") 
List<Project> findProjectByUser(Long id_user);
```

I hope it works